# Is this an inversion problem?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, arrays, permutations

I understand that total inversion in a sequence is the number of swaps that need to be done, to sort the sequence. And the best approach to solve this problem is to count swaps in a merge sort of the sequence.

Now I can think of another problem whose application I need. Imagine I have two unsorted sequences with permutation P1 and P2, how do I calculate the number of swaps to make P1 have same permutation as P2. i.e Instead of using a sorted sequence as the goal of my inversion calculation how do I use an unsorted sequence with permutation P2.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the sequence given by $P_2$ be the sorted order of the elements. For simplicity let your elements be the integers $0,1..., n-1$. In this example, let $n=3$. If $P_2 =[1, 0,3,2]$. Then this permutation will be interpreted as $1 < 0<3<2$.

To be able to use the above idea in your problem, you can let array $Rank$ be an inverted index of size $n$. That is the indices of $Rank$ represents each element and the value of each index is the index of the elements in $P_2$. Using the example above $Rank[0]  =1$ while $Rank[1]= 0$. Now, when comparing two elements, use their value in $Rank$.  With this, 1 is less than 0, because  $Rank [1]<Rank[0]$.

You can uae a hash table to represent $Rank$ in case your elements are not $0,1..., n-1$.